# Service not starring after mariadb default 'datadir' changing. In Redhat server linux 7.7 has Mariadb(10.4) galera cluster

Tags: mariadb, redhat, galera

In windows, I can able to change MariaDB 'datadir' and service also restarting smoothly.

In RedHat server Linux, I am unable to change the default of 'datadir'(under [mysqld] in my.cnf file) for MariaDB when I am trying to start service its showing error in MariaDB service status

```
  Process: 9243 ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 11537 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 11515 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 11509 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

I thought this problem with Galera cluster I changed Galera config(under [galera] in my.cnf.d/server.cnf) too but not use, this time I got a different error.

```
  Process: 7180 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 7308 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 7304 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Is there any license problem or config problem.
please review my problem and suggest to me.